# UWP AdaptiveGridView ItemContainerStyleSelector don't work

Tags: c#, gridview, uwp

I'm facing a new problem with UWP. This time i try to show an AdaptiveGrid with different items, so i have a DataTemplate selector for each item and last thing I want to do is: Change the `ItemHeight` of each `GridViewItem` based on it's class. DataTemplateSelector works like a charm.... Therefore i created a `StyleSelector`:

```
public class CardStyleTemplateSelector : StyleSelector
    {

        public Style CategoryStyle { get; set; }
        public Style ReceipeStyle { get; set; }


        public new Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
        {
            switch (item)
            {
                case Category category:
                    return CategoryStyle;
                case Receipe receipe:
                    return ReceipeStyle;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

pretty simple... So i added some styling:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Style x:Key="Category" TargetType="controls:AdaptiveGridView">
        <Setter Property="ItemHeight" Value="240"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Azure" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Receipe" TargetType="controls:AdaptiveGridView">
        <Setter Property="ItemHeight" Value="400"/>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and finalised with this XAML on my page:

```
<controls:AdaptiveGridView
            Padding="{StaticResource MediumLeftRightMargin}"
            animations:Connected.ListItemElementName="itemThumbnail"
            animations:Connected.ListItemKey="animationKeyCategoryOverview"
            DesiredWidth="220"
            Margin="0,50,0,0"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemClick="OnItemClick"

            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Source,Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectionMode="None"
            StretchContentForSingleRow="False"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}"
            >
            <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
                <templateSelectors:CardStyleTemplateSelector ReceipeStyle="{}" CategoryStyle="{StaticResource Category}" />
            </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
```

and in the end... my background doesn't change... So, maybe one of you can point me in the right direction...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of your CardStyleTemplateSelector is incorrect, you need to override its SelectStyleCore to return different styles and the TargetType should be the GridViewItem instead of AdaptiveGridView. For example:

.xaml:

```
<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="Category">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="GridViewItem" x:Key="Receipe">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
</Style>

......

<controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
    <local:CardStyleTemplateSelector ReceipeStyle="{StaticResource Receipe}" CategoryStyle="{StaticResource Category}" />
</controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemContainerStyleSelector>
```

.cs:

```
public class CardStyleTemplateSelector : StyleSelector
{

    public Style CategoryStyle { get; set; }
    public Style ReceipeStyle { get; set; }

    protected override Style SelectStyleCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        switch (item)
        {
            case Category category:
                return CategoryStyle;
            case Receipe receipe:
                return ReceipeStyle;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortnuately, that didn't do the trick :-/ besides that, the ItemHeight property is part of the AdaptiveGrid and not of any GridViewItem. Besides that, i got a workaround with binding to local variables holding the widths...

Comment: The scope of ItemContainerStyleSelector is for each GirdViewItem, if you want to change the ItemHeight property,  you can use Binding. But each item will apply the same height finally even if you set the different he The above method I provided is about how to use ItemContainerStyleSelector to apply different style.

Comment: yes. That's my intetion. At the moment i just display items of ONE class in the source. My further goal is to mix the Items, thats why i wanted to use the StyleSelector, unfortunately, it doesn't work :-/

Comment: So when you tried my method, it didn't work? When I used it, it can change the background well.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work.... may you can give me your complete xaml, maybe i messed something up

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/wcj233/AdaptiveGridViewApp) is the full sample, you can check  it to see if it can work for you.

Comment: sorry for coming back so late. just messed up my xaml, worked :) thanks!